# Will installing the 'upgrade' visual studio 2010 wipe 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

Will installing the 'upgrade' visual studio 2010 wipe 2008?
Or will they both remain installed?
I want them to both remain installed on the system if possible..

Comment: This should be moved to Stack Overflow

Comment: Yes, this should be moved but I don't think it warrants a downvote. It's a good question, merely posted to the wrong site.

Comment: @John Gardeniers It seems the score is reset to zero when the question is migrated to the right site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration/52586#52586

Answer (score 3):

I'm running both concurrently.  They should work fine side by side.  Good luck!

Microsoft agrees too:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

Comment: That link doesn't mention the *upgrade* version